# task (current target is 1.8) and 'compileDebugKotlin' task (current target is 18) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version

Tags: flutter, dart, build.gradle

I have this error since I updated, I will provide my buid, gradle at the project and app level, the settings.gradle, and the lines of code where the error is marked in the MethodCallHandlerlmpl.kt file
Este es el error:

```
BUILD FAILED in 16s
385 actionable tasks: 380 executed, 5 up-to-date
PS C:\Users\HP\StudioProjects\soiese\android> ./gradlew assembleDebug
> Task :emoji_picker_flutter:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

> Task :device_info_plus:compileDebugKotlin
w: file:///C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/device_info_plus-9.1.2/android/src/main/kotlin/dev/fluttercommunity/plus/device_info/MethodCallHandlerImpl.kt:67:50 'getter for defaultDisplay: Display!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: file:///C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/device_info_plus-9.1.2/android/src/main/kotlin/dev/fluttercommunity/plus/device_info/MethodCallHandlerImpl.kt:70:25 'getRealMetrics(DisplayMetrics!): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: file:///C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/device_info_plus-9.1.2/android/src/main/kotlin/dev/fluttercommunity/plus/device_info/MethodCallHandlerImpl.kt:72:25 'getMetrics(DisplayMetrics!): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: file:///C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/device_info_plus-9.1.2/android/src/main/kotlin/dev/fluttercommunity/plus/device_info/MethodCallHandlerImpl.kt:89:47 'SERIAL: String!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':emoji_picker_flutter:compileDebugKotlin'.
> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'compileDebugKotlin' task (current target is 18) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
  Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 9s
385 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 379 up-to-date
```

My build.gradle at proyect level:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    subprojects {
        afterEvaluate { project ->
            if (project.hasProperty('android')) {
                project.android {
                    if (namespace == null) {
                        namespace project.group
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My build.gradle at app level:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
    id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    namespace "com.soiese.proyect"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    // ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }


    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.soiese.proyect"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.22"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.5.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.12.0'
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.4'
}
```

My settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id 'org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention' version '0.8.0'
    id "com.android.application" version "8.2.2" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.22" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.0" apply false
    id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics" version "2.9.9" apply false
}

include ":app"
```

And the error (the lines specified in the console) in the file MethodCallHandlerlmpl.kt;

```
val display: Display = windowManager.defaultDisplay
            val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                display.getRealMetrics(metrics)
            } else {
                display.getMetrics(metrics)
            }

            val displayResult: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
            displayResult["widthPx"] = metrics.widthPixels.toDouble()
            displayResult["heightPx"] = metrics.heightPixels.toDouble()
            displayResult["xDpi"] = metrics.xdpi
            displayResult["yDpi"] = metrics.ydpi
            build["displayMetrics"] = displayResult

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                build["serialNumber"] = try {
                    Build.getSerial()
                } catch (ex: SecurityException) {
                    Build.UNKNOWN
                }
            } else {
                build["serialNumber"] = Build.SERIAL
            }
```

I'm trying to run my app on my Android device